# Eclipse Mars under Linux: Selection overwrites word specific coloring

Tags: linux, eclipse

What I'm trying to say is, when selecting a bit of code, the special coloring a word has (purple for keywords, blue for member variables, brown-ish for local identifiers...) is overwritten by black.

I'm not sure whether this is a Linux thing or if there are some settings I haven't seen. Changing foreground selection color in Preferences unsurprisingly only changes the color the font has and doesn't influence the fact that its color gets overridden - what I'd like is something like a transparent foreground selection color. I'm on Fedora 22 if that's of any relevance.

Ordinary text - color communicates information:
[image]

Selection causes whole text to be completely black:
[image]

Comment: sorry, but this is not a programming question.

Comment: @asgs I figured but I have seen plenty of questions about Eclipse. Where do you suggest I might put it?

Comment: Superuser.com is your best bet.

Comment: @asgs Problems with tools used for programming are on topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: @greg-449 I apologize. I didn't know that.